# Check a property in the response object resolved by supertest using chai-as-promised

Tags: javascript, chai, supertest, chai-as-promised

How do I check for the `body` property using chai-as-promised? I'm trying to access the body of the response as highlighted in the SuperAgent [docs](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#parsing-response-bodies), but the assertion for `.should.have.property('res')` fails. I `console.log(res)` in a separate test and these got these [results](https://pastebin.com/urQDNwL5). Checking for properties such as `domain` and `_events` will satisfy the test.

The specific assertion error is: `AssertionError: expected { Object (domain, _events, ...) } to have property 'res'`.

```
it('should return a response message with success:true and a token', () => {
    return request(app).post('/auth').type('form')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .send({username: 'jbiden', password: 'password'}).end()
        .should.have.property('res') //'domain','_events' satisfy the test
});
```

**EDIT: Answer in comments by Bergi.**

Comment: `.should.eventually.have…`? You're testing the promise object.

Comment: @Bergi Yes. That was it. For some reason I thought `eventually` was just one of the language chains. Thanks.